# Zend Framework - Json::encode return nothing

Tags: php, mysql, json, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have developed a web application using Zend Framework version 2.8 few months ago and i use json serialization to retrieve data from my database.

So heres the problem : I have just open again the project few days agos and i have noticed that the json serialization didn't work anymore in some cases.

For example, if i do some basic json serialization like that it works great :

```php
        $test = array();
        array_push($test,["test" => 1]);
        array_push($test,["test" => 2]);
        array_push($test,["test" => 3]);
        array_push($test,["test" => 4]);
        array_push($test,["test" => 5]);
        return $this->getResponse()->setContent(Json::encode($test));
//[{"test":1},{"test":2},{"test":3},{"test":4},{"test":5}] works!
```

But when i serialize to json with more datas from my database, nothing is displayed, like for example with this request :

```php
        foreach ($results as $activite) {
            array_push($activitesTab,$activite);
        }
var_dump($activitesTab) // $activitesTab is an array of the records of my db and i'm sure that it's not empty 
        return $this->getResponse()->setContent(Json::encode($activitesTab));
```

I don't understand why nothing is displayed, size limit maybe ? But i don't think that is the problem because i want to serialize "just" 100 records from the db.

If someone got an idea, it will be great for me to understand why i have this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you have any errors in php.log file? Any time limit? Memory size? What is Http status code of that response?

Comment: I have since solved my problem, if i remember well, that was an encoding issue because i had some datas with accents which wasn't encoded correctly.